# Acces Cell Data from Paraview Programmable Filter

Tags: python, numpy, paraview

I need to create a programmable filter using Paraview.
The idea is to create a vector called Speed equal to the speed in the non-rotating part equal to the speed+rotational speed in the rotational one.

The problem is that I can't accept the value of the speed in each single cell.

```
input0 = inputs[0]
radius=3
Speed1=input0.PointData["U"]
K=vtk.vtkDoubleArray()
X=input0.PointData["X"]
Y=input0.PointData["Y"]
Z=input0.PointData["Z"]

pdi = self.GetInput()
numPts = pdi.GetNumberOfPoints()

for i in range(0, numPts):
    if X.getvalue(i)^2+Y.getvalue(i)^2<radius:
    temp=U.getvalue(i)
    else:
    temp=U.getvalue(i)+rot
Speed.InsertNextValue(1)
output.PointData.append(Speed, "Speed")
```

The problem is that `X.getvalue(i)` is not working.

Comment: your question is unclear. is the "X" array contained in your dataset PointData or CellData ?

Comment: Also the Speed array has not been created yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "X" is previously created as PointData in a previous Calculator Filter. The only problem is how to access at these data, since they are something like vtkdataarray.

Comment: The subject of the question mention CellData instead, and the body mentions cells as well.

Comment: @mathieuWestphal, you are or right, but for me is quite the same. I need a solution, it is not a problem if working on cells or points.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
X[i]
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://blog.kitware.com/improved-vtk-numpy-integration-part-5/)

Comment: Hey Mathieu, thanks for th answer, but it is not working because X is a vtk

Comment: X is a vtk ? what does it mean ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't finshed the sentences. X is a vtkCompositeDataArray and not a vtkGenericDataArray. Can be this the problem? I'm using Praview 5.4.1 for Windows 64 bit.

Comment: You said that "X has been created in a calculator filter", hence it is a vtkDoubleArray, GetValue should work, You can Try GetVariantValue.

Comment: Yes, X is created in a calculator filter, but I have always:"AttributeError: 'VTKCompositeDataArray' object has no attribute 'GetVariantValue'  and getVariantValue and GetValue and getvalue also. Can be different if the orignal source is OpenFoam based or Ensight? Sorry a lot, but for me it is essential to find the solution.

Comment: How can be possible to switch from VTKCompositeDataArray to other types? Thanks and sorry

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems to work better. At least, I don't have any error.

Comment: I would like to copy the final code for other users and maybe someone can help me to fin a better way to convert VTKArray to float. Thanks a lot! Seems to work better. At least, I don't have any error. I would like to improve how to transform in float.

from vtk.numpy_interface import algorithms as algs

input0 = inputs[0]
X=input0.PointData["Result"]
c=X[1]
f=algs.min(c)
print type(f)

Comment: your last comment was unclear. Please accept my answer if it resolved your problem